# Bulk package updates using Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Is there a way (using conda update) that I can list outdated packages and select or bulk update (compatible) packages in Anaconda?

It doesn't make much sense updating the packages individually as there are hundreds of them.

Answer (score 358, accepted):

You want `conda update --all`.

`conda search --outdated` will show outdated packages, and `conda update --all` will update them (note that the latter will not update you from Python 2 to Python 3, but the former will show Python as being outdated if you do use Python 2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use python 2. Is it possible to filter the outdated for a particular installed version(py27_0)? does `conda update all` updates only compatible version for my py27 environment?

Comment: Yes, `conda update --all` will only install packages that are compatible with one another, and it will not update you from Python 2 to Python 3.

Comment: Don't forget to add _conda_ to your path, `export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH`

Comment: `conda search --outdated` shows you all the available versions of each installed AND outdated package, that is a bit too much in many cases,,, Personally I prefer to use `conda update --all`, that shows what's going to be installed and prompts for confirmation: you reply `N` and you have a compact list of outdated packages.

Comment: `conda update --all` also differs from `conda search --outdated` in that it runs through the solver, meaning some packages that have newer versions may not be updated if other packages have dependency restrictions (or, for example, `conda update --all` won't update from Python 2.7 to Python 3.4).

Comment: I got an error message for packages having unsatisfiable dependencies when trying `conda update --all` but `conda update anaconda` did the job.

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't it better to stick with the latest version of the anaconda **meta package**? If you install any package to a version higher than what the anaconda meta package has, your anaconda meta package version will be changed to `custom-py36_0` (assuming Python 3.6). Unless you have a very good reason to manually update one specific package or another, I don't think `conda update --all` is good practice, and `conda upgrade anaconda` should be used instead.

Comment: is running command line `conda update anaconda` (or `conda update --all`) the same as updating packages in Anaconda Navigator -> Environments -> selecting Upgradable and manually applying upgrades? Thanks.

Comment: I have also come across `conda update conda`. Is it the same as `conda update anaconda`?

Comment: I have just found [this blog](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/) where author Jake VanderPlas gives some term explanations regarding _Anaconda_ and `conda`. It answered many questions I had.

Answer (score 15):

Before you proceed to `conda update --all` command, first update conda with `conda update conda` command if you haven't update it for a long time. It happent to me (Python 2.7.13 on Anaconda 64 bits).

Comment: 64 bit, you mean?

Comment: At the very least, probably would have made more sense as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: "It happened to me", *what* happened to you?

Answer (score 2):

the Conda Package Manager is almost ready for beta testing, but it will not be fully integrated until the release of Spyder 2.4 (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Roadmap). As soon as we have it ready for testing we will post something on the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/spyderlib). Be sure to subscribe

Cheers!

Comment: How does this answer replies to the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
# list packages that can be updated
conda search --outdated

# update all packages prompted(by asking the user yes/no)
conda update --all

# update all packages unprompted
conda update --all -y
```